# Automatic C/C++ mock generation for XCTest - CMock/OCMock?

Tags: c, xcode, ocmock, xctest, cmock

I want to develop using C & C++ using XCode 5.  I particularly like the integration of XCTest and Xcode and the CI capability that you get by using OSX Server.  I want to have a mocking framework, and ideally one where the mocks are automatically generated, as this seems most likely to ensure that the mocks follow a standard format (and themselves are not going to have errors).

Q1. I can't see how OCMock can work for mocking C & C++: is this possible?

Q2.  CMock seems to be great, but it relies on Unity.  Is it possible to integrate CMock into XCTest?

Q3.  Does anyone have any other suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1. OCMock can only mock methods on Objective-C classes, objects, and protocols.

Q2. What is Unity? (And I'm asking this as the maintainer of OCMock...)

Q3. There are several options for C and C++, I don't have much experience, never mind a strong recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for the update, much appreciated.  Unity test framework is at https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Unity, docs/info are at http://throwtheswitch.org/white-papers/unity-intro.html.  I want auto mock generation for C/C++ that can be integrated into Xcode easily, and CMock looks very nice for this. I'm going to play around with Unity to see if I can get it to play nicely with XCTest, I'll post details back here if I can get it to work properly.

Comment: Hmmm, I've pursued this and it's turning out to be far more trouble than it's worth.  I'll come up with another plan I think.